# Azure Bicep - Object reference not set to an instance

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I'm trying to create a simple App Service Plan with the below code.

```
param Location string = 'eastus'
resource appServicePlan1 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2020-12-01' = {
  name: 'myasp'
  location: Location
  sku: {
    name: 'S1'
    capacity: 1
    }
}
```

Below is the Azure CLI command that I'm using to execute the above Bicep script

```
az deployment group create --name deploy1 --resource-group az-devops-eus-dev-rg1 --template-file main.bicep
```

Below is the screenshot

[image]

All this was working earlier. I'm using the latest version of Bicep (v0.9.1) which is available as of today.

Any pointers on why this is occurring now would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try another region (just to test)? I think there was an issue lately within certain regions. Your code looks correct so far

Comment: Having the exact same issue, but for region westeurope. I use API version 2022-03-01

Comment: Same here and for different regions. I'm following the MS Learn learning path, and deploying the code from there is also failing with that error message. But I see no incidences in the Azure status page.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just had this issue in a MS workshop. We solved it by adding a empty properties-element to the appServicePlan. Ex.

```
param Location string = 'eastus'
resource appServicePlan1 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2020-12-01' = {
  name: 'myasp'
  location: Location
  properties: {}
  sku: {
    name: 'S1'
    capacity: 1
    }
}
```

Comment: lol, this broke my release

Comment: I was initially very happy with the move from ARM to bicep but I’ve recently hit several problems like this and it’s curbed my enthusiasm!

Comment: @RobBowman Not a BICEP issue. You'd encounter this issue with raw ARM template.